# Is there a way to create a mock dataset of an actual survey, using R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a mock dataset of an actual survey?

I will be analyzing and reporting results of a survey that is currently being conducted.

I don't want to wait until the survey is closed to start analyzing the data. While the data is being collected, I would like to start working on the script for analysis and visualizations, and for that I need data that are similar to the data being collected.

Is it possible to create a mock dataset with the actual structure and variables of the survey? The survey has different types of questions, including arrays, single choice, multiple choice, and open ended questions. I know I could wait until I have 10 or 20 responses and start working on that? Could I create a random dataset based on those responses?

I'd be grateful if someone could give some ideas about this. Cheers.

Comment: Look into the functions `sample.int`, `sample`, `runif`, `rnorm`. Open ended questions would be tricky if you want something more complex than a random set of letters

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format (e.g. column names etc.) of your expected data. Here, you can simulate binary vectors:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1337)

select_m_out_of_n <- function(n, m) {
  if (m > n) stop("Can not choose more items than the number of options")

  res <- rep(FALSE, n)
  selected <- sample(n, m)
  res[selected] <- TRUE
  res
}

# q1 one out of 5
simulated_survey <- tibble(person_id = seq(3)) %>%
  mutate(
    # single choice
    q1 = person_id %>% map(~ select_m_out_of_n(5, 1)),

    # binary choice
    q1 = person_id %>% map(~ select_m_out_of_n(1, 1)),

    # multiple choice
    q2 = person_id %>% map(~ select_m_out_of_n(5, 2)),
    q3 = person_id %>% map(~ select_m_out_of_n(4, 2))
  )
simulated_survey
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   person_id q1        q2        q3       
#>       <int> <list>    <list>    <list>   
#> 1         1 <lgl [1]> <lgl [5]> <lgl [4]>
#> 2         2 <lgl [1]> <lgl [5]> <lgl [4]>
#> 3         3 <lgl [1]> <lgl [5]> <lgl [4]>

# answers of first person
simulated_survey %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  as.list()
#> $person_id
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $q1
#> $q1[[1]]
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> 
#> $q2
#> $q2[[1]]
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> 
#> 
#> $q3
#> $q3[[1]]
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>